# Finding specific list of xlsx rows in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

Can anyone help me finding specific columns from an Excel sheet in Matlab? My file looks a bit like this:

```
% First set of data

x   y

1   2
2   4
3   6
4   8
5   10
6   12
7   14
8   16
9   18
10  20

% Second set of data    
% Empty line

1   1.5
2   3
3   4.5
4   6
5   7.5
6   9
7   10.5
8   12
9   13.5
10  15

% Third set of data 
% Empty line

1   0.5
2   1
3   1.5
4   2
5   2.5
6   3
7   3.5
8   4
9   4.5
10  5
```

What I want Matlab to do is to find:
- For every set of data (individually), find this data and plot in the same figure.

So I want Matlab to find the new set automatically after the empty line. One of my problems for now is that I use about 1500 rows for one data set and the next data set is a bit smaller. So I could imagine using something like:

```
x=xlsread('Filename.xlsx','A1:AN');
```

Answer (score 0):

**You might try this:**

> I have assumed that all sets of data doesn't have any empty lines between themselves, while each set of data have only one empty line following them.

```
%// read all set of data
%// you might additionally add range if you want to avoid non-numeric data such as string
a = xlsread('Book1.xlsx');

%// add NaN values at the end if not already present
if ~isnan(a(end,1))
  a(end+1,:)=nan;
end

%// detect NaN rows
idx2=find(isnan(a(:,1)));

%// detect start rows for each set of data
idx1=[1 idx2(1:end-1)+1];

%// find number of data sets
n=numel(idx1);

%// create corresponding cell array
out=cell(n,1);

%// put each set of data inside a cell
for k=1:n
  out{k}=a(idx1(k):idx2(k)-1,:);
end

%// plot each set of data separately 
%// using 'hold all' instead of 'hold on' gives different colors for each data set
hold all
cellfun(@(x) plot(x(:,1),x(:,2)),out);
hold off
```